# ListView with Switch widget, onItemClick doesn't fire

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a custom Adapter inheriting from ArrayAdapter. I lay out the rows and everything works great. The problem is when I add a Switch widget to the row layout, my onItemClick (and onItemLongClick) handlers for the ListView no longer fire.

Here's some simplified code showing the problem. ListPlain uses a layout without the switch and works fine, ListWithSwitch just has the addition of Switch widget and the clicks don't fire.

https://bitbucket.org/akent/listviewswitchtest

What is it about the Switch widget that could possibly be affecting the behaviour of the parent layout?

Comment: could you post your code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, I worked it out already. The solution is to set `focusable="false"` on the `Switch` in the `layout XML`.

```
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false" />
```